# Search database across multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this query to search my database for values in three columns. This works great up until I input a query where values span multiple columns.

So for example, if I were to input a name and a company "John McDonalds", the result comes back empty. Is there a way to allow searching across multiple columns at the same time?

```
if (isset($_POST['search']) && $_POST['search'] != '') {

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tickets_info WHERE (name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')) OR (company LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')) OR (ticket LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%'))");
        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['search'], $_POST['search'], $_POST['search']);
        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $result_array = array();

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            array_push($result_array, $row);

        }

        $stmt->close();

        header("Content-Type: application/json");

        echo json_encode($result_array);

    }
```

Comment: Simple answer: no, it should never be done in a way like this. If you ever have to do something like this you have to rethink your database structure

Comment: If you have to do it this way, break apart the string by spaces, and search each individual word. Just know that it's a bit tougher and you'll probably get some false positives.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to search multiple terms, one option is to split the incoming `$_POST['search']` and then search the database multiple times. This means your search algorithm complexity multiplied by n, the number of words.

```
if (isset($_POST['search']) && $_POST['search'] != '') {
    $search_terms = explode( ' ', $_POST['search'] );
    $results = array();
    foreach( $search_terms as $search_term ) {
        array_push( $results, search_db( $search_term ) );
    }

    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($result_array);
}

function search_db( $search_term ) {
    global $conn;

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tickets_info WHERE (name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')) OR (company LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')) OR (ticket LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%'))");
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', search_term, search_term, search_term );
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $result_array = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($result_array, $row);
    }
    $stmt->close();

    return $result_array;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm receiving the following error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')' on array_push( $results, search_db( $search_term );

Comment: I'm just typing code into the editor here using yours as a jumping off point so it is easier to follow for you albeit untested - That error should be showing up in your IDE -- looks like I missed a closing parenthesis on that line. I'm editing the code now.

Comment: Okay, I'm receiving this error after using your updated example: Call to a member function bind_param() on null

Comment: Looks like that's because `$conn` is inside of a function. I'll add global $conn; to the top of that function.